# Laravel 8, NPM Wepback API configuration problem, using Yarn on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

Using `npm run dev` results in the error:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. configuration.module.rules[10] has an unknown property 'loaders'
```

- Jetstream Version: 1.6
- Jetstream Stack: Livewire
- Laravel Version: 8.14
- PHP Version: 7.3.0
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL v8.0

### Steps to reproduce:

- Navigate to directory hosting Laravel 8 project
- Run command `rm -rf node_modules` and wait for the command to complete
- Run command `rm package-lock.json`
- Run command `npm cache clear --force`
- Run command `sudo npm install --global npm` - this updates NPM (Node Package Manager)
- Run command `sudo yarnpkg install`
- Run command `sudo yarnpkg add babel@latest`
- Run command `sudo yarnpkg add webpack@latest`
- Run command `sudo yarnpkg add webpack-cli@latest`
- Run command `sudo yarnpkg add vue-template-compiler --save-dev --production=false`
- Run command `sudo yarnpkg add sass-loader@8.* sass --save-dev --production=false`
- Run command `sudo npm install --global cross-env`
- Run command `yarnpkg run dev`

NPM is supposed to return a success message, but clearly something is either broken or misconfigured...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved through  either an NPM or Yarn update